# NGINX proxy_cache hanging / timing out with one large CSS from backend ngx_pagespeed Server

Tags: css, nginx, mod-pagespeed

I'm stuck with NGINX 1.4.4 hanging on a request for a large(ish) minified CSS file coming from a backend ngx_pagespeed Server that deals with it fine?

Set-up:

[London] eac2.marvelled.co.nz --> [Australia] roselle.marvelled.co.nz --> Expressjs:82

Hanging file: http://eac2.marvelled.co.nz/assets/css/app.min.css 
Backend Pagespeed: http://roselle.marvelled.co.nz/assets/css/app.min.css

"eac2"
NGINX [1.4.4]
ngx_pagespeed = OFF [1.6.29.7-3453]
proxy_cache
Role: Caching layer - developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/downstream-caching

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

"roselle"
NGINX [1.4.1]
ngx_pagespeed = ON [1.6.29.7-3453]
proxy_cache
Role: Optimization layer

There are various reasons why this set up is required for development so I'm looking
specifically for some ideas on what could be causing the "eac2" layer CSS to hang.

I've tried various work arounds by just having "eac2" serve the CSS file directly but I must be missing something simple for this not to work out-the-box.

Originally I thought it was the buffering so I've tired this:

proxy_buffering on;
proxy_buffers 32 16k;

Has anyone been in a similar situation to save me going down the painful debugging / log route.

Kind Regards

Martin

Tagging a bit off as no ngx_pagespeed one?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but similar issues created on github have been resolved some time ago.
So I suspect this is not an issue anymore in the later releases.

In the future, you could probably better redirect such questions to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ngx-pagespeed-discuss for a faster answer.